# Is there a way to import multiple Git projects as git projects into Eclipse by using a script/command line?

Tags: eclipse, github, vagrant, pydev, egit

It'd be nice if I could have it as part of my vagrant config, so other potential devs could start coding on these projects right away.

Comment: Hard to understand your problem without more details

Comment: Why is it hard to understand? Perhaps one detail I should add is that I use Arch Linux for this. I have been able to install dependencies by doing commands like this: ```yaourt -S --noconfirm eclipse-pydev```. I was hoping there would be commands that would import the projects into eclipse.